# Are there partial results when running Athena queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I want to know if all Athena queries are transactional (assuming I just operate on Athena tables and not Iceberg tables). I want to leverage Athena to generate CSVs at specific paths in S3. Lets say I run a simple select query with a query result location in S3 specified

```
SELECT *
FROM athenadb.tablename
// queryResultLocation = "s3://bucketname/path/to/queryresult/"
```

Is there ever a chance that the query will fail but there will be data pushed to the s3 path anyway?

Comment: No, if query fails, in that case no data will be saved in s3.